# objc_msgSend 15 crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, c, xcode, crash

I'm trying to track down a bug and i've got a crash log that looks like this:

```
0    libobjc.A.dylib     objc_msgSend + 15

1    CoreFoundation  __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 14

2    CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 272

3    CoreFoundation  __CFRunLoopRun + 1232

4    CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 356

5    CoreFoundation  CFRunLoopRunInMode + 104

6    GraphicsServices    GSEventRunModal + 74

7    UIKit   UIApplicationMain + 1120

8    MyApp  main.m line 21
```

Unfortunately the MyApp line is the only place among any thread that mentions my application.

Any pointers for what may be causing a crash like this?

thanks!

Comment: is that what the output window in xcode is logging??

Comment: You should also keep placing NSLogs in your code to see where exactly your code crashes. Is it even getting into `applicationDidFinishLaunching`? Which is the last place in your code where NSLog works before it crashes?

Comment: its a crash log sent from a user device and i'm not sure how to go about replicating it since theres only rweferences to system code!

Comment: You should **NOT** fill up your application with NSLog statements! NSLog is slow slow slow. And it doesn't help in such a case anyway, since the problem could be anywhere in the app.

Comment: Have you tried turning on NSZombie to see if you are messaging a deleted object?

Comment: You can use breakpoints to log out messages to the console.  On an aside, here's an interesting article related to objc_msgSend() which may or may not help.

Comment: You should read [So you crashed in objc_msgSend()](http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2008/09/22/objc_explain_So_you_crashed_in_objc_msgSend.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like the other answers suggest, this is because of a zombie object. A call is being made to an object who's instance has already been deallocated.

Try and locate the crash by using Zombie instruments and enabling zombie objects in the scheme. This should help you pin point which object is deallocated and which method is causing the crash. Most often, this occurs when delegation is used.

This should be helpful: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/Instruments_help_articles/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects/FindingMessagesSenttoDeallocatedObjects.html

Answer (score 0):

The app is trying to call something that doesn't exist any more. And the call is triggered from another runloop, via a timer or something similar, but is already released.

So you might want to check if you have any timers setup on objects that could be gone before the timer fires.

Comment: maybe a timer, since the second line reads `__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__`